# install4j: View / print startup parameters

Tags: java, install4j

Is there a way to debug and print the startup parameters with the install4j services? Tracing the variables back to the varfile can take quite a bit. I was hoping there was a native method in install4j to print out the startup command line.

Comment: You may be able to find that information in the log files. Those can be found in the temp directory.

Comment: Currently that is not possible. What information do you need that is not printed in the log file?